# dSym missing in unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I got a crash report from my unity game. In the performance reporting tool I can see:

```
    Native Crash - <unknown> (Unknown File)
Thread 0 (crashed)
0   .                                   <unknown> 
1   libgpg.so                           <symbols missing for uuid: xxx> 
2   libgpg.so                           <symbols missing for uuid: xxx> 
3   libgpg.so                           <symbols missing for uuid: xxx> 
4   libc.so                             <unknown>
```

I can upload dSym using panel.

Where I can find dSym for android 7.

I know the way for the IOS as described [here](https://forum.unity.com/attachments/performance-reporting-missing-symbols-pdf.264794/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [post](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000292166-Symbolicate-Android-crash).

In particular:

> From Unity 5.3.5p2 and 5.4.0, the Android symbols are stored in your
>   Unity installation folder.
>
> You can find the Android symbols here:
>
> For MacOS:
>
> ```
> /Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono/Release/Symbols
> ```
>
> For Windows:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\mono\Release\Symbols\armeabi-v7a\libunity.sym.so
> ```

Comment: I cannot upload libunity.sym.so. I guess it should be something of format like in Temp/StagingArea/Symbols, but in this version I'm missing this folder (so symbols are not uploaded automatically) From logs I can see that I had the symbols in december 2017.

Comment: ahhh, the problem is probably connected with Google play games for unity: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity so I guess they should provide additional symbols?